# Why is pyspark write() so slow compared to show()?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using Pyspark 3.1.1 locally for a simple calculation without changing any configs apart from setting `setMaster` to "local".

I have a very large file which I read into Pyspark, it's a 17.7 GB text file with over 87 million lines which I read in as a csv with one column.

Here's some code showing what I'm doing, B is a long string that is cut into pieces of 3 characters which are then exploded into individual rows and used for joining.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StringType

df1 = spark.read.csv(path_to_file1, schema=schema1)
df1 = df1.withColumn('A', f.expr("substring(data, 1, 10)"))
df1 = df1.withColumn('B', f.expr("substring(data, 11, length(data)-13)")).drop("data")

split_data = f.udf(lambda x: [x[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(x), 3)], ArrayType(StringType()))
df1 = df1.withColumn('B', split_data(f.col('B')))
df1 = df1.withColumn('B', f.explode(f.col('B')))

df2 = spark.read.csv(path_to_file2, schema=schema2)
df2 = f.broadcast(df2)

df = df1.join(df2, on='B', how='inner')
```

When I do `df.coalesce(1).show()` in the end everything just takes a couple of seconds.

However when I do `df.write.csv()` instead I get 142 stages with each taking around 22 seconds to complete adding up to over 50 minutes! Each stage writes between 11 and 19 MB result. When I add a `coalesce(1)` before the write it's 1 stage that of course complains about lacking sufficient memory but also seems to take a horribly long time. I did not wait for it to finish because of the memory warnings.

=======================================

Why is the `write`-call so much slower? Both calls return the final result, so shouldn't both calls be executing the entire DAG? How can just writing results to disc take so much longer than everything else?

On the other side, when just using `show` how does Pyspark read a 17.7 GB csv file, does all the operations including the `explode` and the join within just a few seconds? Does the DAG even calculate the entire dataset or just a chunk? I do coalesce after all.

I did experiment with setting `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` to 4 or 8, this has helped me before with smaller data sets in this situation, but now it doesn't seem to matter, I always get 142 tasks.

=======================================

Where is the actual bottleneck in this scenario?

How can I speed up the `write`-operation?

Would this be a problem on a cluster too or is it a local problem?

Comment: show() collects 20 rows (by default) to a driver and print them unlike write(), which have to write all your data to a disk

Comment: But does it only calculate enough data to collect 20 rows or does it execute the complete DAG on ALL the data?

Comment: just enough to get 20 rows. as soon as it gets results, it prints them out.

Comment: 2 possible bottle neck I can see in your code : the UDF and the broadcast. Broadcast can speed up the process but it depends on the size of the dataframe. It could be a bottle neck or a advantage.

Comment: The broadcast dataframe has 2505 rows with very little data per row. Then it's most likely the UDF plus the explode. After all the already 87 million rows are multiplied by some significant factor due to the explode. I will check how many rows there are afterwards.

Comment: @Steven I found out the table gets inflated to 5.9 billion rows. So, I rest my case, one hour is actually pretty good for that amount.